# Unhandled securityError in mxmlc command line but not in CS5 or Flash Builder 4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flashbuilder4

For some reason I am able to build/publish and run my project in cs5 and from inside flash builder 4 without problems, but once I step out to the command line all sorts of stupid things start happening, this being one of them. Is there a reason that the mxmlc is not able to handle this properly from the command line? I know of a solution with the crossdomains, but I've gotten along fine without that and this seems more like a bug than an actual project requirement. Also, the reason I am working with the commandline is because I need to automate the creation of flash projects, so if there is another method, I would be willing to try it.

Comment: A few more unrelated questions:

Is there a way to resize the display window when running a flash builder 4 project? The video is always larger than the window when I run it. It seems like it's 130% w and h in size, and I'm not touching the stage properties. This is only an issue in FB4, in CS5 it runs properly at a resolution of 800x800.

Comment: If you have an unhandled security issue then why don't you just handle it? It seems obvious to me. The difference between the compilers is probably a setting somewhere that is different in command line

Comment: You should post another question for the scaling issues you are getting.

Comment: Well the thing is I've handled this issue in CS5 and it doesn't come up in Flash Builder 4 (inside the IDE) so this definitely seems like a situational issue that is dependent on the environment. I don't think changing it once more here will completely solve the problem, so I need a more general solution.

Comment: If your getting the error you have to handle it. you did not exactly post any code or even the error code so I highly doubt anyone can help you. And just so you know security errors are generally ignored in the local sandbox, once you publish it, it will break which is probably what you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

Be certain that the compiler you target with the command line is as recent as the one you are using with Flash CS5 and Flash Builder. Would this by any chance be an AIR 2.7 Project?